# Problem with my Wi-Fi connection

Tags: wireless

My Wi-Fi name is "minions" but why Ubuntu is showing "minions 6", "minions 5" and "minions 4". What all these sub Wi-Fi names mean?

Is someone hacking my network or something like that?

[image: minions wifi]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Edit-Connections* which is at the end of the shown list. *Clear* all the saved *minions* shown there.Then type *sudo service network-manager restart* in the terminal. Now enter the password of your wifi.

It probably happened because you entered the password 3-4 times incorrectly.

Comment: If my answer helped, then please accept it. It will help me get some reputation.